# Passing an implicit parameter to Future.recover

Tags: scala, future, implicit, partialfunction

I want to pass an implicit parameter to a partial function I use to `recover` my `Future`s.

```
def delete(id: Long) = ... { implicit something =>
  serviceLayer.doSomething(id).recover(errorHandler)
}

def errorHandler: PartialFunction[Throwable, Result] = {
    // I want to access the implicit parameter here
    case e@SomeException(message) => ... and here
    case _ => ... and here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then your `errorHandler` needs to receive `something` as an [implicit parameter](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-parameters.html):

```
def delete(id: Long) = ... { implicit something =>
  serviceLayer.doSomething(id).recover(errorHandler)
}

def errorHandler(implicit something: Something): PartialFunction[Throwable, Result] = {
    // Access something here
    case e@SomeException(message) => ... and here
    case _ => ... and here
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This should have been my first try! But for some reason I assumed too much and thought that it wouldn't work!! There is another problem but it needs another question, the `errorHandler` is a value in a superclass which I have to override here but probably I'll get compile error if I override it with a `def` with an `implicit` parameter